# Conflict with Redirect to index.php and folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I rent an Apache web server. The folder architecture is like this:

> - root
>
>   - src
>   - template
>   - less
>   - www
>
>     - css
>     - js
>     - jpeg

The web server serves only the `www` directory. And I use a .htaccess to redirect to HTTPS, remove the `www.` and redirect all request to the `index.php` except if a file exist in the `www` folder.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Remove WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domaine\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://domaine.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]

# Redirect all route to index.php
# Except the files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?$1/ [NC,L,QSA]
```

The problem is the when I request a folder name. The folder is redirected twice to `index.php`!

Example: When I request `http://domaine.com/css`, the request is redirected to `https://domaine.com/index.php?css/?css/`.

How to solve the double redirect?

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either exclude directories from your last rule OR add a trailing slash using a redirect rule to directories to avoid this behavior

Otherwise last rule rewrites directories without slash to `/index.php` and due to missing slash `mod_dir` module redirects by appending a trailing slash.

Also you should move `www` rule before `http->https` rule to **avoid multiple 301 redirects** for a request that is `http://www.domaine.com/`.

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
  Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

# Remove WWW and use https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(domaine\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

# Redirect to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# add trailing slash for directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

# Redirect all route to index.php
# Except the files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php?$0/ [NC,L,QSA]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before you test this change.

Comment: I don't want allow the visitor to access to my subdirectory. Only to the files

Comment: `subdirectory` content won't be listed with these rules and `DirectorySlash Off` is security risk. Read about it in Apache manuals. There are better ways to handle this problem.

Comment: I read the Apache documentation and disable Indexes options to avoid security risk. Even if my server didn't have it. because I redirect all route which are not a file to my index.php

Comment: Finally, I use your solution. The directory are redirected to index.php with 2 slash at the end but this problem is unrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I resolv my problem. I remove the automatic slash at the end with the DirectorySlash directive. Now that's work and all my directories are hidden. Only the file are visible.

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
  Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
Options -Indexes
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On

# Remove WWW and use https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(domaine\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

# Redirect to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* /index.php?$0 [NC,L,QSA]
```